# rewrite within lambda with respect to an equivalence relation

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The question is, if I know that `forall x, f x ≡ g x` (where `≡` is some equivalence relation, and `f`, `g`, are functions), what is the correct `Proper` instance which will let me rewrite `f` with `g` in some larger term linked by the equivalence relation?

Assume functional extensionality is available if required - which I guess will be required for this?

Some sample code to demonstrate the question better:

```
Require Import Setoid.
(** Feel free to assume FunExt *)
Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.
Section FOOBAR.
  Variable T: Type.
  Variable f: T -> T.
  Variable g: T -> T.

  Variable t0: T.
  Variable combiner: (T -> T) -> T -> T.

  Variable equiv: T -> T -> Prop.
  Infix "≡" := equiv (at level 50).

  Axiom equivalence_equiv: Equivalence equiv.


  Axiom F_EQUIV_G_EXT: forall (t: T), f t ≡ g t.

  (** Check that coq can resolve the Equivalence instance **)
  Theorem equivalence_works: t0 ≡ t0.
  Proof.
    reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Theorem rewrite_in_lambda:
    combiner (fun t => f t) t0 ≡
    combiner (fun t => g t) t0.
  Proof.
    intros.
    (* I wish to replace x with y.
    What are the Proper rules  I need for this to happen? *)
    rewrite F_EQUIV_G_EXT.
  Abort.
End FOOBAR.
```

The proof goes through if we can replace `f` with `g`, but I'm not sure how to do that. What additional power do I need for my equivalence relation for this to succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `pointwise_relation` from the coq stdlib: [Link here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Classes.Morphisms.html#pointwise_relation)

I also copy-pasted the definition in case the link bitrots:

```
 Definition pointwise_relation (R : relation B) : relation (A -> B) :=
    fun f g => forall a, R (f a) (g a).
```

So, we wish for a proper instance of the form:

```
Axiom proper: Proper (pointwise_relation T equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) combiner.
```

That is, if the first function is pointwise equal, and the second argument is equal, then the result is equal.

Here is the full code listing which compiles:

```
Require Import Setoid.
Require Import Relation_Definitions.
Require Import Morphisms.

(** Feel free to assume FunExt *)
Require Import FunctionalExtensionality.
Section FOOBAR.
  Variable T: Type.
  Variable x: T -> T.
  Variable y: T -> T.

  Variable t0: T.
  Variable combiner: (T -> T) -> T -> T.

  Variable equiv: T -> T -> Prop.
  Infix "≡" := equiv (at level 50).

  Axiom equivalence_equiv: Equivalence equiv.
  Axiom proper: Proper (pointwise_relation T equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv) combiner.

  Axiom X_EQUIV_Y_EXT: forall (t: T), x t ≡ y t.

  (** Check that coq can resolve the Equivalence instance **)
  Theorem equivalence_works: t0 ≡ t0.
  Proof.
    reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Theorem rewrite_in_lambda:
    combiner (fun t => x t) t0 ≡
    combiner (fun t => y t) t0.
  Proof.
    intros.
    (* I wish to replace x with y.
    What are the Proper rules  I need for this to happen? *)
    setoid_rewrite X_EQUIV_Y_EXT.
    reflexivity.
  Qed.
End FOOBAR.
```

Comment: It does not compile with Coq 8.8.0. Compilation breaks on the first `reflexivity`. I filed [an issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7874) about this.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug report :) Also, thanks for answering all coq questions, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: As mentioned in the bug report, this is not a bug. In 8.8 and later, you need to declare axiomatic instances explicitly using the `Existing Instance` command. This is backward-compatible.